# React-Admin. how to filter the list on line entries for AutocompleteInput component

Tags: reactjs, odata, react-admin

version react-admin: 2.9.5

My component:

```
<ReferenceInput 
    label="Клиент"
    source="customerId" 
    reference="Customer" 
    alwaysOn={true}
    filterToQuery={searchText => ({displayName: searchText})}
    >
      <AutocompleteInput optionText="displayName"  />
</ReferenceInput>
```

**i'm expected that the request parameter filter will look like this**

```
contains(tolower(displayName),'fg')
```

but in reality it turns out to be

```
displayName eq 'fg'
```

**Ask: what I have to do to get the expected result?**

Answer (score 1):

I did not find solutions, I had to make a custom component